# Bitcoind suspend when Synchronizing blocks

Tags: bitcoind, client, synchronization

My bitcoind started synchronising blocks. The bitcoind version is 0.93. When the bitcoind found an orphan blocks in the synchronising process, it seems stop and did not work. the message from the log like this:2015-01-08 06:08:19 ProcessBlock: ORPHAN BLOCK 184, prev=0000000000000002d79cd7069cedd05f49716354590bd5518b18a513b3b4d513

I need restart it and it would continue synchronising. This case happens many times. sometimes the bitcoind found orphan blocks in the synchronising process, it would continue work.  I don't where is wrong. Any ideas? Big thanks.

note: my system is CentOS

Comment: please, tag the OS you are using: linux, windows, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new version [(0.10 / RC1)](https://bitcoin.org/bin/0.10.0/test/) has a [rewritten block-download mechanism which significantly improves synchronization](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/0.10/doc/release-notes.md#faster-synchronization) which could result in less similar issues.

A workaround for the current version is to deploy the `-maxconnections=<n>` option and set it to a low number to reduce parallelism and thus receive less orphans in total. Set `-maxconnections=1` to receive little to no orphans (essentially only for the newly announced blocks).

You can also use the `-maxorphanblocks=<n>` option (which has a default value of 750), try decreasing it and the daemon will probably bypass the stall point, as keeping less max orphans will prevent your system from running out of resources (eg RAM), which I suppose is what currently happens.

Another workaround is to just download the [bootstrap.dat torrent](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bitcoin/files/Bitcoin/blockchain/bootstrap.dat.torrent/download) if you are still many weeks behind the current block.